# SASS - Complex Media Queries

Tags: css, sass

Consider a container element with a toggle-able side menu. I can open and close the side menu simply by toggling the `open` class on container, affecting both child elements in my CSS. The .container spans the width of the screen and the side menu is 200px wide.

```
<div class="container">
    <aside></aside>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

I have this implemented and it works well. Now let's introduce some responsive design to my `.content` class. I want my media queries to target when the **div.content's width is greater than 1000px**, so I'll need to account for whether or not the side menu is open.

```
.container {

  &.open {
    @media (min-width: 1201px) { // 1000px + 200px for the menu
      .content {
        ...
        #id { ... }
        div { ... }
      }
    }
  }

  &:not(.open) {
    @media (min-width: 1001px) {
      /* Duplicate from above! */
    }
  }
}
```

This totally works, but it requires I duplicate the CSS in both queries. Is there any way I can write this so as not to copy-paste the .content CSS? Can mixins support complex chunks of CSS? Anyway to "comma separate" the queries in SASS?

Comment: Media queries do not assess element style information so you can't do this with media queries, but yes it is possible to group media queries with a comma, e.g. `@media (min-width: 1201px), (min-width: 1001px)` (although in that case the `1201px` query would be redundant).

Comment: Hmm... no. It's working for me. I'm just asking for better syntax. Read the question again please, you don't understand.

Comment: You said "I want my media queries to target when the **div.content's width is greater than 1000px**" and I'm saying that you can't do that. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: I can and I did, lol. The way I have it set up, the media queries fire only when the .content width is greater than 1000px. It's a creative solution. I'm just wondering if there's a way I can keep the SASS dry.

Comment: Oh. That's... odd o_O Well I can't help you then.

Comment: It's pretty straight forward. When the menu is open `&.open` there's an extra 200px of width on screen. So target 1000+200 `@media (min-width: 1201px)`. When not open `&:not(.open)` the width of .content is the same as the width of the screen, so media query as usual `@media (min-width: 1001px)`.

Comment: Oh, so the screen size is completely dictated by the width of the container and the menu. That makes sense.

Comment: Right. Sorry I didn't make that clear. I do wish we had element queries though.

Comment: There's no "Sass way" to do what you're asking other than writing a mixin.  You can't `@extend` across media queries.

Answer (score 1):

This worked.

```
@mixin content-1000px {
  .content {
    ...
    #id { ... }
    div { ... }
  }
}

&.open { @media (min-width: 1201px) { @include content-1000px; } }
&:not(.open) { @media (min-width: 1001px) { @include content-1000px; } }
```